# Attaching a metabox to a single post

Tags: metabox

I've been using metaboxes for a while now, and enjoyed their flexibility. However, I am now in a situation where I need the metabox to appear only for **a specific single post or page**, and **not** for the whole (custom)-post-type. Is it possible to do so?

Your kind assistance would be most welcomed.

TIA
Matanya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are familiar with the how to create metabox using [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) already, I'll skip to the relevant bits.

You can either conditionally `add_meta_box` depending on the current post title, or ID, (this is the preferred method) or, you can conditionally `remove_meta_box` depending on the the post displayed.

To detect the current post ID you would `get_query_var( 'post' )` and move on from there, using `get_post(get_query_var('post'))` if further post data is required to filter out the metabox.

Comment: Thank you so much for your brief yet informative answer. Best. Matanya.

Comment: You're welcome. Note I changed `id` to `post` in `get_query_var`, just in case you find out it doesn't work.